# Generate a WARC from local site files

Tags: twitter, warc

I have downloaded a Twitter archive export. It's a few folders of JavaScript, HTML, etc. and a top-level "Your archive.html". This is all viewable via a local browser, but I would like to generate a WARC from these local site files.

I have looked at `wget --warc-file` option but I'm not seeing a way to point `wget` at local files.

Does anyone know of a way to create a WARC out of a locally saved site?